# hive calculates wrong sum for json object

Tags: json, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have an external table with one column - data, where the data is json object

when I'm running the following hive query

```
hive> select get_json_object(data, "$.ev") from data_table limit 3;     

Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201212171824_0218, Tracking URL = http://master:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201212171824_0218
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=master:8021 -kill job_201212171824_0218
 2013-01-24 10:41:37,271 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
 ....
 2013-01-24 10:41:55,549 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
 Ended Job = job_201212171824_0218
 OK
 2
 2
 2
 Time taken: 21.449 seconds
```

But when I'm running the sum aggregation the result is strange

```
hive> select sum(get_json_object(data, "$.ev")) from data_table limit 3;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
 set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
 set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_201212171824_0217, Tracking URL =   http://master:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201212171824_0217
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=master:8021 -kill  job_201212171824_0217
2013-01-24 10:39:24,485 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
.....
2013-01-24 10:41:00,760 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201212171824_0217
OK
9.4031522E7
Time taken: 100.416 seconds
```

Could anyone explain me why is that? And what should I do in for that works properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive seems to be taking the values in your JSON as `float`s instead of `int`s, and it looks like your table is pretty big so Hive is probably using the "exponent" notation for big float numbers, so `9.4031522E7` probably means `94031522`.

If you want to make sure you're doing a `sum` over int, you can cast the field of your JSON to int and the sum should be able to return you an int:

```
$ hive -e "select sum(get_json_object(dt, '$.ev')) from json_table"
8.806305E7
$ hive -e "select sum(cast(get_json_object(dt, '$.ev') as int)) from json_table"
88063050
```